# Not able to get component in shalow function of enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have this test.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Login from './index';

describe('Login', () => {
  it('should render correctly in "debug" mode', () => {
    component = shallow(<Login />);
    console.log(component.debug());
    const element = component.find('.logoImg');
    expect(element.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

I expect this to pass as i have `<img className='logoImg'>` but it did not as it. 
For debugging, I log the component i found[image]

This show that i render

```
<Route>
  [function children]
</Route>
```

I am new. How can i render the component. Any help please.
**index.js**

```
<Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/"
              exact
              component={compose(
                withAuth,
                withTracker,
              )(SelectionPage)}
            />
            <Route
              path="/refill"
              exact
              component={compose(
                withAuth,
                withTracker,
              )(Refill)}
            />
            <Route path="/login" component={withTracker(Login)} />
            <Route
              path="/"
              component={compose(
                withAuth,
                withTracker,
              )(SelectionPage)}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
```

I have this as index.js.
**Edit**
I tried by changing my index.js and got same results.

```
 <Provider store={store}>
   <Router>
     <Route path="/" component={withTracker(Login)} />        
   </Router>
 </Provider>
```

Comment: You need to import expect in your test. There are no imports for 'expect' in your test file.

Comment: @Nayanshah did that but no change

Comment: Could you update the code or show me which expect you imported. Is it from chai? something like this import { expect } from 'chai' ?

Comment: @Nayanshah, if he is using the `expect` provided by Jest, there is no need to import it in the tests.

Answer (score 0):

When you use [shallow](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md) to render a component you are not rendering the component children.

So, when you shallow render the component in *index.js* that contains the code:

```
<Provider store={store}>
   <Router>
     <Route path="/" component={withTracker(Login)} />        
   </Router>
 </Provider>
```

You are actually not rendering the `Login` component.

If you want to test the `Login` component, you should shallow render the `Login` component, not the component where you associate a route to `Login`.

Comment: Thank you for reply this was not problem but I have learn new thing might help you to for that visit https://medium.com/netscape/testing-a-react-redux-app-using-jest-and-enzyme-b349324803a9. Lot of brain storming i got Jest require diff config if u want to test connected components